# Issue while starting WLDF Console Extension

Tags: java, weblogic

Any fix to avoid this exception while starting WLDF Console? Thanks.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 218762506 in class file com/bea/diagnostics/dashboard/ChartPanelApplet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 218762506 in class file com/bea/diagnostics/dashboard/ChartPanelApplet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an earlier Sun bug report on this issue, with JDK 1.4

you are mostly running JDK 1.6 but take a look at the [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4975146).

Short Summary (gleaned [from this forum](http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst2126_magic-number-problem-on-javafirefox.aspx)) :

> The Java plug-in of your browser tries
> to get some .class file from the
> current location (your server) and
> fails because your server returns some
> custom 404 page. Let's try to check
> the Java console to see what really is
> requested. Please, run the Java
> console, set the trace level to 5
> (highest level).

Enable the [Java console on Windows for IE browser](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098887) and see if it gives a detail on which URL is giving the 404 or some other error.

**Further Reading**

[Oracle forum question](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8360309&#8360309)

Comment: @Chaintanya: My answer still holds true

Comment: Thank you for your time. It seems this issue doen't have a solid fix.